# Can we rename the "app" folder in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I'm trying Angular2 and for experimentation I tried to rename the **app** folder where my Angular2 application should go to **my-app** folder.

The problem is, after rename the folder and rename the reference to my folder in my index.html the application gives me a 404:

> GET http://localhost:56204/my-app/main 404 (Not Found) : angular2-polyfills.js:126

Is **app** a mandatory naming convetion to Angular2 run?

If not, how can I change the **app** folder name?

Comment: Are you using SystemJS, add your SystemJS config to the question

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you use `angular2-polyfills.js`. And it seems that it doesn't find your application's root path. As explained [here](https://github.com/SamVerschueren/angular2-polyfill), angular2-polyfills needs a path to your app too. Did you change it ?

For your second question, angularjs 2 doesn't depends on any folder architecture.